# How to assign configuration variables as combination of other parameters defined in the omnet.ini in OMNeT++

Tags: simulation, omnet++, ini

I want to set the `warmup-period` as the sum of some parameters that I need in my simulations. I wrote this but I always get a Syntax Error or parsing Error

```
**.airspace.interArrivalTime = ${iat = 15..30 step 3}
**.airspace.landingTime = ${lt = 15..30 step 3}
**.parkingarea.takeoffTime = ${tot = 15..30 step 3}
**.parkingarea.parkingTime = ${pt = 15..30 step 3}
warmup-period = ${$lt + $tot + $pt}
```

I don't know how to properly define my warmup period that way (if possible). I also read the 10.4 section of OMNeT++ 5 manual (https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/) but I did not find any solutions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`warmup-period` is an option of simulation, it is not a regular parameter. It cannot be expressed using other parameters in `omnetpp.ini`.
However, it is possible to set the value of this option based on other parameters in C++ code:

1. Add to your NED file additional parameter, for example:

   ```
   double warmupPer; // in seconds
   ```
2. Add to `omnetpp.ini`:

   ```
   **.warmupPer = ${$lt + $tot + $pt}
   ```
3. Somewhere in `initialize()` of your module add these lines:

   ```
   double warmup = par("warmupPer");
   getSimulation()->setWarmupPeriod(warmup);
   ```